# placing link inline with horizontal radio buttons

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to put an info button next to my jquery radio button controls, and I can't figure out how to do it.  The closest I got was adding style="float:left;" to the  tag, but that messes up the legend.  I want it to look the same as it does normally, just with the info button directly to the right of the controls.  I'm not great with CSS so any help would be much appreciated!

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <legend>Pass Keys:</legend>
                        <input type="radio" name="OTonoff" id="OTon" value="on">
                        <label for="OTon">On</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="OTonoff" id="OToff" value="off">
                        <label for="OToff">Off</label>           
</fieldset>
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7wr13xv9/

Comment: Just debug and override some of the rules, [example](https://jsfiddle.net/bympqhg6/) there might be better ways but not sure.

Comment: That looks really good!  That's just what I wanted.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply flex to the direct container instead:

```
fieldset {
display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
}
```

Add this:

```
legend {
flex:0 0 8em;
}
```

http://autoprefixer.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add some classes. This way you can target your markup accurately. Change:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
```

to

```
<div class="fieldcontain" data-role="fieldcontain">
```

Then, use flexbox to distribute child elements of this div evenly.

```
.fieldcontain {
display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
}
```

Comment: That works good for putting the info button to the right but it messes up the legend.  Is there any way to keep the legend how it is (same spacing and presence) while still having the info button to the right? See the effect it has on the legend here: https://jsfiddle.net/7wr13xv9/6/